# Why is my C++ object becoming nulled when I pass a lua value containing it to a lua script/function ue4, lua machine

Tags: c++, lua, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, lua-api

I've exposed some C++ functions to Lua so that I can retrieve/manipulate data from objects of class UTableBase(Not user data). But whenever I pass FLuaValues containing a non user data object to a function or script it seems like the object pointer is getting garbage collected or just not working.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to stop it?

Some code

Blueprint code
[image]

Lua code
[image]

C++ code
CSVLibrarySubsystem.h

```
UCLASS(Blueprintable)
class MYMODDINGBOX_SDK_API UTableBase : public UObject {

    GENERATED_BODY()


public:
    TMap<FString, UBaseTypeColumn*> Columns;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    TArray<FString> GetCSVRows();

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    TArray<FString> GetCSVColumns();


    //Value getters
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsStringArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<FString>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsStringMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, FString>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetArrayElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, FString& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetMapElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, FString& ReturnVal);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, int32& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsIntegerArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<int32>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsIntegerMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, int32>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetArrayElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, int32& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetMapElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, int32& ReturnVal);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, float& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsFloatArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<float>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsFloatMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, float>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetArrayElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, float& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetMapElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, float& ReturnVal);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, bool& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsBoolArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<bool>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetColumnAsBoolMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, bool>& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetArrayElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, bool& ReturnVal);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool GetMapElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, bool& ReturnVal);


    //Value Setters
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsStringArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<FString> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsStringMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, FString> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetArrayElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, FString NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetMapElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, FString NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddArrayElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddMapElementAsString(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, FString NewValue);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, int32 NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsIntegerArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<int32> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsIntegerMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, int32> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetArrayElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, int32 NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetMapElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, int32 NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddArrayElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, int32 NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddMapElementAsInteger(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, int32 NewValue);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, float NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsFloatArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<float> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsFloatMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, float> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetArrayElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, float NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetMapElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, float NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddArrayElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, float NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddMapElementAsFloat(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, float NewValue);


    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, bool NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsBoolArray(FString Row, FString Column, TArray<bool> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetColumnAsBoolMap(FString Row, FString Column, TMap<FString, bool> NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetArrayElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, int32 Dex, bool NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool SetMapElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, bool NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddArrayElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, bool NewValue);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool AddMapElementAsBool(FString Row, FString Column, FString Dex, bool NewValue);

    //
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void PrintColumnTypes();

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    bool CheckColumnType(FString ColumnName , UColumnTypes Type);

    //Parse string
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void ParseToTable(FString CSVStr);
    
    TArray<FString> SetUpArray(FString ArrayString);

    TMap<FString, FString> SetUpMap(FString MapString);

    TPair<FString, FString> SetUpPairs(FString PairString);

    FString CleanUpString(FString DirtyString);

    TMap<FString, int32> CheckTypeRow(TArray<TArray<const TCHAR*>> Table);
    
    void interpretType(TArray<TArray<const TCHAR*>> Table);

    //Variable
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
    bool OverrideWhenEmpty = false;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
    bool OverrideContainers = false;

    //bool OverrideWhenEmpty = false;
};
```

LuaCSVTablePackage.h

```
UCLASS()
class MYMODDINGBOX_SDK_API ULuaCSVTablePackage : public ULuaBlueprintPackage
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:
    ULuaCSVTablePackage();

    UFUNCTION()
    FLuaValue PackageTest();
    
    UFUNCTION()
    FLuaValue CSVGetter(FLuaValue Obj, FLuaValue Row, FLuaValue Column);
};
```

LuaCSVTablePackage.cpp

```
ULuaCSVTablePackage::ULuaCSVTablePackage()
{
    Table.Add("CheckCSV", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, LuaCheckCSV)));
    Table.Add("LoadCSV", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, LuaLoadCSV)));
    Table.Add("UnloadCSV", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, LuaUnloadCSV)));

    Table.Add("GetCSVRows", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, LuaGetCSVRows)));
    Table.Add("GetCSVColumns", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, LuaGetCSVColumns)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsString", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsLuaString)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsStringTable", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsLuaStringTable)));
    Table.Add("GetTableElementAsString", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetTableElementAsLuaString)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsNumber", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsNumber)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsNumberTable", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsNumberTable)));
    Table.Add("GetTableElementAsNumber", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetTableElementAsNumber)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsBool", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsLuaBool)));
    Table.Add("GetColumnAsBoolTable", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetColumnAsLuaBoolTable)));
    Table.Add("GetTableElementAsBool", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, GetTableElementAsLuaBool)));

    Table.Add("SetColumnAsString", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, SetColumnAsString)));
    Table.Add("SetColumnAsTable", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, SetColumnAsStringTable)));
    Table.Add("SetContainerElementAsLuaValue", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, SetContainerElementAsLuaValue)));
    Table.Add("AddContainerElementAsLuaValue", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, AddContainerElementAsLuaValue)));

    Table.Add("PackageTest", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(ULuaCSVTablePackage, PackageTest)));
    Table.Add("CSVGetter", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(ULuaCSVTablePackage, CSVGetter)));
    Table.Add("ExternalExposeTest", FLuaValue::Function(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(UCSVTableFunctionLibrary, ExternalExposeTest)));
}

FLuaValue ULuaCSVTablePackage::PackageTest()
{
    return FLuaValue("Test working");
}

FLuaValue ULuaCSVTablePackage::CSVGetter(FLuaValue Obj, FLuaValue Row, FLuaValue Column)
{
    UObject* FromLua = ULuaBlueprintFunctionLibrary::Conv_LuaValueToObject(Obj);

    if (FromLua == nullptr) { 
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Some debug message!"));
        return ULuaBlueprintFunctionLibrary::LuaCreateNil();
    }

    UTableBase* CTable = Cast<UTableBase>(FromLua);

    //Return value
    FString ReturnVal;

    if (!CTable->GetColumnAsString(Row.ToString(), Column.ToString(), ReturnVal))
    {
        if (CTable->Columns.Contains(Column.ToString()))
        {
            UE_LOG(CSVTableLuaLog, Warning, TEXT("Problem accessing value at column %s"), *Column.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            UE_LOG(CSVTableLuaLog, Warning, TEXT("Problem accessing value at row %s"), *Row.ToString());
        }

        return ULuaBlueprintFunctionLibrary::LuaCreateNil();
    }

    return FLuaValue(ReturnVal);
}
```